# File Operations - Copy and Move - Delphi

Tags: delphi, file-io

I need to do a two fold operation in Delphi.

First is reading a directory and copy all of the files into a backup folder.  If any of the files are currently in use as being written to and/or open, then bypass that file.

Second is to move the file to another directory.  Again, if any of the files are currently in use as being written to and/or open, then bypass that file.

I have used file copy and move before, but I am unsure as to how to detect whether a file is being written to and/or open.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use Windows.pas' `CopyFile(PChar(sFrom),PChar(sTo),false)` it will return false when the copy fails, and `GetLastError` will return an error-code explaining why.

Comment: Thanks.  I had the same thinking, but wanted to hear someone else verify my logic.

Comment: Its working for me if I remove the last argument (`false`) otherwise I get `too many arguments`.

Comment: That may be because you're using `CopyFile` as defined by SysUtils.pas, not Windows.pas.